# Missing some tag HTML while scraping using requests python on GCP VM

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, request-headers, python-requests-html

I'm trying to scrape a website, the results were as expected if I run my code on my own local server, but if I deploy to a GCP VM, some of the HTML tags are missing. I've made sure that the source code is the same both locally and on GCP.

Of interest is the fact that if I change my headers, then I get more missing tags. So far, I've found that these headers work the best:

```
headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1 Edg/87.0.4280.141",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Connection": "keep-alive"}
```

Is the missing tags problem caused by the headers being sent, or by something else happening in the GCP VM?

Comment: I doubt GCP is somehow filtering your traffic. The question doesn't have a lot of info to make a solid assumption, unless one has experienced with this directly. My guess is the website you are querying is returning different results based on IP (assuming the code on GCP and locally are indeed 100% the same). Can you describe how you are you are noticing that "HTML tags are missing"? Sounds like you are doing `len(bs4.find_ll("<div>"))` or something - so not sure what you mean.

Comment: Inspecting the raw HTML locally and on GCP is your best-bet (after querying, dump the HTML to file). Might just be a message saying "can't access this website" when you query from GCloud, which would give you some better ideas.

Comment: i print out both locally and on GCP like this, 
`print(table.find_all("tr"))`. Locally output : `<tr><td>A</td></tr><tr><td>B</td></tr><tr><td>C</td></tr>`. GCP output : `<tr><td>A</td></tr><tr><td>B</td></tr>`. The C is missing, like truncated HTML tags not to the end.

Comment: In such case my next best guess would be you are running two different _versions_ of either (a) your requests library, or (b) BeautifulSoup. On GCP and locally run `pip freeze | grep "beautifulsoup4\|requests"` (replacing `requests` with whatever request library you are using) and ensure the versions are the same across both environments. If your application is properly packaged with a `requirements.txt` always make sure to add the latest working version number for each dependency - saves you a lot of headaches down the line.

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap troubleshooting done in comments:

- GCP by itself does not filter headers.
- Depending on the website, scraping results may differ because of different IP.
- If you encounter any discrepancies between dumps made locally and on GCP, make sure code and all dependencies are the same.

You can find more information about scraping from GCP [here](https://jrizmal.medium.com/deploying-a-python-web-scraper-on-google-cloud-platform-12fe24e57bb0).